# How much load should HBase be able to handle?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

Using the java HBase API, how many rows of data should it be able to handle in one scan request? 
Let's assume each row is between 100-200 bytes of data.

Is retrieving 15 million rows in one scan request unreasonable?
Is deleting using 15 million row keys in one request unreasonable?

I understand an accurate answer to this question depends on many factors such as how the hadoop environment is set up.
But I would like to know what is the typical limit of a default configured HBase installation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my experience it is not unreasonable. Obviously it would require adequate memory resources on BOTH client and server sides. Furthermore, for scans specifically: you'd need to be careful with cache settings and also in terms of iterating the results of the scan. By default, the .next() in scan would return only 1 row, so you'd be doing way too much round-tripping, so you can do .next(NUM) and empirically configure the right level of NUm to make sure you have enough memory on both sides and aren't doing too much back-and-forth.

Comment: It is NOT reasonable. This would be a wrong  design according to me. If you need to do bulk operations, don’t forget that HBase relies on HDFS and that you can use YARN + MapReduce + HBase libs  to do bulk extracts or bulk updates in a parallel way.